# Agrupar y Ordenar datos según una columna MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Estoy trabajando con una tabla en **MySql**, la cual almacena todas las reservas de pasajes, y está diseñada de esta forma:

```
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
|id|     empresa     |    nombre     |  estado_solicitud  | 
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
|1 |     VAB         |    CRISTIAN   | PERDIDO_P_IDA      |  
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
|2 |     VAB         |    FELIPE     | PERDIDO_P_VUELTA   |  
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
|3 |     VAB         |    FELIPE     | RESERVADO          |  
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
|4 |     VAB         |    JUAN       | RESERVADO          | 
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
|5 |     VAB         |    MARCELO    | RECHAZADO          | 
+--+-----+-----------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Necesito contar el número de pasajes reservados, perdidos y rechazados, ademas deben mostrarse en el siguiente orden:

```
1° RESERVADO
2° PERDIDO_P_IDA  (PASAJE IDA PERDIDO)
3° PERDIDO_P_VUELTA  (PASAJE VUELTA PERDIDO)
4° RECHAZADO
```

De momento tengo esta consulta en `MySQL` pero no realiza lo que necesito:

```
SELECT estado_solicitud, count(*) as numero_pasajes 
FROM reserva_pasajes_db 
WHERE empresa='VAB' 
GROUP BY estado_solicitud
```

Me está contando los pasajes, pero no me genera el orden. he intentado utilizar el `ORDER BY` pero no sé como colocarlo.

Comment: Cúal sería el criterio del orden? de mayor cantidad a menor?

Comment: no no, que simplemente mantenga el orden que mostré ahí.  y que si los estados que no aparezcan puedan aparecer con valor null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolverlo puedes usar `case` y `when` con el `group by` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT estado_solicitud, count(*) as numero_pasajes, 
case
  when estado_solicitud='RESERVADO' then 0 
  when estado_solicitud='PERDIDO_P_IDA' then 1
  when estado_solicitud='PERDIDO_P_VUELTA' then 2
  when estado_solicitud='RECHAZADO' then 3
  end 
  as orden
FROM reserva_pasajes_db 
WHERE empresa='VAB' 
GROUP BY orden
```

De esa forma puedes mostrar los datos en el orden que esperas, aunque solo se mostraran los estados que tengan registros en la base de datos.

Para mostrarlos aun si no tienen registros lo puedes hacer con `union` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 'RESERVADO' as estado_solicitud, count(*) as numero_pasajes
FROM reserva_pasajes_db 
WHERE empresa='VAB' and estado_solicitud='RESERVADO'
union
SELECT 'PERDIDO_P_IDA', count(*) 
FROM reserva_pasajes_db 
WHERE empresa='VAB' and estado_solicitud='PERDIDO_P_IDA'
union
SELECT 'PERDIDO_P_VUELTA', count(*) 
FROM reserva_pasajes_db 
WHERE empresa='VAB' and estado_solicitud='PERDIDO_P_VUELTA'
union
SELECT 'RECHAZADO', count(*) 
FROM reserva_pasajes_db 
WHERE empresa='VAB' and estado_solicitud='RECHAZADO'
```

Puedes ver como funcionan ambas consultas en el siguiente enlace:

<kbd>[Demostración](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/243bd2/3)</kbd>

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: hola the-breaker, excelente, es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @h6gignacio Si te ha sido de utilidad marca la respuesta como aceptada, es importante contribuir con la pagina, para mas información revisa
[Recordemos a la gente que es bueno aceptar respuestas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4288/recordemos-a-la-gente-que-es-bueno-aceptar-respuestas).

Comment: si.. sólo tengo una duda.. tengo el problema de que a veces no siempre están esos estados, me explico.. puede que existan solo reservados y me gustaría que independiente de que están en orden.. me gustaría que igual aparezcan los demas estados pero con valor 0, ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: tengo un par de soluciones para esos casos, puedo enseñarte una de esas, dame un momento.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias

Comment: @h6gignacio ahí lo tienes.

Comment: excelente.. muchas gracias. funciona a la perfección

Comment: @h6gignacio, para este tipo de casos es que conviene tener una tabla de "`solicitudes_estados`", donde tienes un `id` y `nombre` para los estados, y con un `LEFT JOIN` todo queda más simple y prolijo.

Comment: si @Marcos ese es el plan B

Comment: @the-breaker, exactamente y es una solución que escala para futuros "estados". Casi me olvido, también podría agregar una columna `orden` y así también modificar el orden del resultado...

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas compacta seria:

```
SELECT estado_solicitud, count(*) as numero_pasajes 
FROM reserva_pasajes_db 
WHERE empresa='VAB' 
GROUP BY estado_solicitud ORDER BY FIELD
(1,'RECHAZADO','PERDIDO_P_VUELTA','PERDIDO_P_IDA','RESERVADO') DESC, 2;
```

El 1 indica el numero de la columna por la que se va a ordenar, 'estado_solicitud'.

El 2 al final indica que también se va a ordenar por la columna 'numero_pasajes'